# stacking multiple column into one column

Tags: r

I have a data with multiple columns and i want to stack it. My data looks like

```
January February    March

20.5733 47.3457 47.8473
-9999   -9999   -9999
18.8403 41.3779 44.6814
23.0879 35.9153 41.216
43.49   31.85   40.17
-9999   -9999   -9999
-9999   -9999   -9999
15.1745 43.8709 46.5024
```

and i need the data as follows

```
Janaury 20.5733
January -9999
January 18.8403
Janaury 23.0879
January 43.49
January -9999
Janaury -9999
January 15.1745
February    47.3457
February    -9999
February    41.3779
February    35.9153
February    31.85
February    -9999
February    -9999
February    43.8709
March   47.8473
March   -9999
March   44.6814
March   41.216
March   40.17
March   -9999
March   -9999
March   46.5024
```

Thanks
Juvin

Comment: Try `library(reshape2);melt(df1)`

Comment: Did you try `stack`?

Answer (score 2):

Going purely from your question title, look at `stack`, for example, `stack(mydf)`.

Here are the first 10 rows:

```
> head(stack(mydf), 10)
       values      ind
1     20.5733  January
2  -9999.0000  January
3     18.8403  January
4     23.0879  January
5     43.4900  January
6  -9999.0000  January
7  -9999.0000  January
8     15.1745  January
9     47.3457 February
10 -9999.0000 February
```

Popular packages include "reshape2" and "tidyr" with which the approach would be something like:

```
library(reshape2)
melt(mydf)
```

and

```
library(tidyr)
gather(mydf, var, val, January:March)
```